# Accessing StreamingAssets resources from C++ DLL in Unity on Android

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine

I have developed a C# application in Unity for Android. Additionally, I built a custom external C++ DLL which is properly loaded and accessible from the C# code. I have also added some .xml files into the StreamingAssets folder which works as expected as I can see those files loaded into the .apk.

Currently my problem is that I'm not able to access such xml files from my C++ library. On one hand I'm not sure how to do it correctly, on the other I tried multiple unsuccessful approaches including trying to understand in which cwd was my DLL loaded and then navigate to the files I needed (which didn't work as I constantly receive an access denied error).

**EDIT:**

Your replies actually put me on the right track and I solved the issue as follow:

- During the OnStart() phase of my application, I use the UnityWebRequest class to extract from the JAR file the required files and then I save them in the Application.persistentDataPath
- After that, I pass to my DLL the new path to each file which allows me to access them without any issue.

Comment: In a built app I would copy them into the [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) which is usually accessible for the targets normal folder system. As it says there the path on Android is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files` and can also be accessed using `android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android the StreamingAssets are in a jar. That may well be the reason why you can't access them, but as you can see in the manual you can use the `WWW` class to retrieve files there.

> On Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file
>   (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed
>   files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to
>   retrieve the file, you need to use additional software to see inside
>   the .jar archive and obtain the file.

(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)

Comment: Thank you, I knew about that bit of documentation. The problem is that the UnityWWW class can only be called from the C# side of the code. I need to load the xml files directly from my C++ DLL.

Answer (score 1):

> On Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file
>   (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed
>   files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to
>   retrieve the file, you need to use additional software to see inside
>   the .jar archive and obtain the file.

---

A JAR is a package file format typically used to aggregate many Java class files and associated metadata and resources into one file for distribution. JAR files are archive files that include a Java-specific manifest file. **They are built on the ZIP format and typically have a .jar file extension.**

---

This means that you can work with **jar** files the same way as you do with **zip** files.
There is a fork for [minizip](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip) with examples on how to use it.